# iOS5 Notification drop-down menu: is there a way to know when the user presses the clear button on my apps notification on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uilocalnotification

Is there a delegate method or some way to get the event when a user clears my applications notifications from the Notification drop-down menu? The `UIApplication` delegate

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

is only called when they select an event from the list but it isn't called when the list is cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if a user clears your notification, it's the same as if it never arrived.

Comment: That's too bad! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you clear notification or swipe on notification message this method will be called in appdelegate.m file.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    //When notification is pressed on background it will enter here

    //Get strings based on information on your json payload for example
    if([[userInfo objectForKey:@"keyword"] isEqualToString:@"value"]){
        //redirect/push a screen here for example

}
```